# keycloak throw authentication error from custom protocol mapper

Tags: keycloak

I've crated a java custom protocol mapper extended from `AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper`

This mapper call a rest api, I want to show a custom message error on login based on te result of response. But I do not know how to do it

I am overriden the method

```
protected void setClaim(IDToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, UserSessionModel userSession)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an Exception that extends org.keycloak.services.ErrorResponseException. There you can override

```
@Override
    public Response getResponse() {
        if (response != null) {
            return response;
        } else {
            OAuth2ErrorRepresentation errorRep = new OAuth2ErrorRepresentation(error, errorDescription);
            return Response.status(status).entity(errorRep).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
        }
    }
```

passing any object as entity to be returned as part of the response.